# Firebase Java Admin SDK don't work

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am following the documentation on Firebase website on setting up an Java Admin SDK. So I add the dependency to the build.gradle, and added the following code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/Users/idanaviv10/Desktop/mapit-33290-firebase-adminsdk-fdy24-a1d0505493.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
          .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
          .setDatabaseUrl("https://mapit-33290.firebaseio.com/")
          .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog");

        DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");

        Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
        users.put("alanisawesome", new User("June 23, 1912", "Alan Turing"));
        users.put("gracehop", new User("December 9, 1906", "Grace Hopper"));

        usersRef.setValue(users);
    }
    public static class User {

        public String date_of_birth;
        public String full_name;
        public String nickname;

        public User(String date_of_birth, String full_name) {
            // ...
        }

        public User(String date_of_birth, String full_name, String nickname) {
            // ...
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is when I am trying to get data (adding a listener) or trying to save data (like in the example) nothing happened. I am running the code in eclipse, I can see in the console that it print "Done", but when I check the database (on the firebase console on the browser) nothing change.
[image]

Comment: You have to make HashMap to set the value to the database see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) under Saving data

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried copying the exact example from the documentation, and it still not working.

Comment: Any database errors in the console? Check the permissions.

Comment: There is no error in the console, and read and write are both set to true in the permissions.

Comment: do you have these fields (date_of_birth, full_name, nickname) under your users child? Add the database construction to your question

Comment: you dont have users child, your database structure is different to the class which you pass with the insert function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem, the problem was that the program will terminate before connecting to the Firebase server. What you need to do is to delay the termination of the program, by either calling `Thread.sleep(20000);`, or like I did it

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!scanner.nextLine().equals("Quit")){}
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: That is indeed a common problem when you first start accessing the Firebase Database from non-Android Java. We've had the question a few times before, but clearly those didn't show up when you search for it. Hopefully this answer will be found by others stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 5):

One other thing you can try is to explicitly wait until the `setValue()` task is complete using the [`Tasks`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Tasks) API:

```
Task<Void> task = usersRef.setValue(users);
try {
    Tasks.await(task);
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
    // Handle error if necessary
}
```

Comment: HI there is ref.push().setValueAsync(users)  in firebase admin sdk. Did you look , how to handle it . I am facing same issue , i added child listeners but they are not working . I even tried  "while  loop"  in main thread to wait  but listener call back is not working.

Comment: You have to wait for the `ApiFuture` to resolve. Easiest way is to call `get()` on the returned Future.

Comment: I am doing geton async future . It is loading data into firebase but the callback listeners that were added on firebase database is not executing . I have taken code from google firebase java sdk ..     I am adding comment below for full code

Comment: there is no such method `setValue(users)` which returns `Task` in Firebase Admin Java SDK

Comment: The old versions did (v5). This question is couple of years old.

Answer (score 0):

below code is pushing data into firebase database using java async call api from firebase sdk but listeners code is not executing . I am running below code in server side backend.

```
 public enum Firebase {
INSTANCE;

FirebaseApp firebaseApp;


public void initilizeFirebaseApp(ConfigLoader configReader) {

    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicInteger message1 = new AtomicInteger(0);
    InputStream firebaseSecret = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ServiceAccount.json");
    final GoogleCredentials credentials;
    try {
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(firebaseSecret);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while reading Firebase config file." + e.toString());
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

    Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<>();
    auth.put("uid", "my_resources");

    FirebaseOptions options = new Builder()
            .setConnectTimeout(1000)
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)
            .setDatabaseUrl(configReader.getFirebaseDatabaseURL())
            .setStorageBucket(configReader.getFirebaseStorageBucket())
            .setProjectId(configReader.getFirebseProjectId())
            .build();

    firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);


    System.out.println(firebaseApp.getName());
    //System.out.println(firebaseApp.getName());
    // Use the shorthand notation to retrieve the default app's service
    FirebaseAuth defaultAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseDatabase defaultDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    // The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference("/analyst_profiles");


    DateTime dt = new DateTime(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(dt.getValue());
    //test data push
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data
    AnalystProfiles analystProfilesObjTemp = new AnalystProfiles("test2", Long.toString(dt.getValue()), "dsds", "ds", "ds",
            "dsa2323", "32ddss232");

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            AnalystProfiles post = dataSnapshot.getValue(AnalystProfiles.class);
            System.out.println(post);
            //done.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }


    });


    CompletableFuture<String> welcomeText = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            ref.push().setValueAsync(analystProfilesObjTemp).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while waiting for future", e);
        }
        return "ok";

    }).thenApply(x -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println("Listeners code is not executing");
        return x;
    });


    done.countDown();
    try {
        System.out.println(welcomeText.get());
        done.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public void testdataLoad() {

    // The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference("/analyst_profiles");


    DateTime dt = new DateTime(java.util.Date.from(Instant.now()), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(dt.getValue());
    //test data push
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data
    AnalystProfiles analystProfilesObjTemp = new AnalystProfiles("test2", Long.toString(dt.getValue()), "dsds", "ds", "ashutsh",
            "dsa2323", "32ddss232");

    CompletableFuture<String> welcomeText = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            ref.push().setValueAsync(analystProfilesObjTemp).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while waiting for future", e);
        }
        return "ok";

    }).thenApply(x -> {
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    });



    try {
        System.out.println(welcomeText.get());

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
ApiFuture api=/*your reference to database*/usersRef.setValueAsync(users/*the data*/);

Object o = api.get(/*time out*/8,TimeUnit.SECONDS/*unite for time out her is seconds*/);
```

And at last you can check with

```java
api.isDone();
```

[image: screenshot]