# Firebase admin sdk setValue and setValueAsync are never completed

Tags: java, firebase, scala, playframework, firebase-admin

I am trying to write into my realtime db using firebase admin sdk.
I am using. But for some reason the request is not executing. I am using scala. But I feel its relevant to java too as I have just converted java code to scala.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>7.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have correctly set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and auth part of it works. Also I have set the rule for the db as,

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Code :

```
 def updateFireBase(updated: WxResponseString, symbol: String): Future[Unit] ={
    println("start")

    try{
      val options = FirebaseOptions.builder.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault)
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/").build
      val app: FirebaseApp =FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
      println(app.getOptions.getDatabaseUrl)
      val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference
      val symbolRef = ref.child("ticker/" + symbol.toLowerCase())
      println(symbolRef.toString)

      return Future{
        println("this is start")
        symbolRef.setValueAsync(updated.last).get() // gets stuck here forever
        println("this is end !!!!!!!!!!!!!")

      }
    } catch {
      case e:Exception => {
        logger.error("err", e)
      }
    }
    Future.successful()



  }
```

`println("this is start")` is executed but `println("this is end !!!!!!!!!!!!!")` is not. I have checked that the db url is correct and made sure the thread is blocked by calling get on it.
I went through [JavaEE and Firebase admin sdk - setValueAsync not pushing data to realtime firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043813/javaee-and-firebase-admin-sdk-setvalueasync-not-pushing-data-to-realtime-fireb) and other questions, but did not help.
Also I tried the same code with `setValue` and its callback is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this:

```java
 def updateFireBase(updated: WxResponseString, symbol: String): Future[Unit] ={
    println("start")

    try{
      val options = FirebaseOptions.builder.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault)
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/").build
      val app: FirebaseApp =FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
      println(app.getOptions.getDatabaseUrl)
      val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference
      val symbolRef = ref.child("ticker/" + symbol.toLowerCase())
      println(symbolRef.toString)

       ApiFuture<Void> future = symbolRef.setValueAsync(updated.last);
       future.get();

    } catch {
      case e:Exception => {
        logger.error("err", e)
      }
    }
    Future.successful()
  }
```

Comment: I tried that , did not work. 
It was an issue with `FirebaseOptions.builder.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault)`
so I changed it to `GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fileStream)` and it worked.
Weird thing is that I did not get any errors while using getApplicationDefault

Comment: hmm realy strange. Thx for sharing the soluition :)